# Delete an object's property given its location

Tags: javascript, object, associative-array

Given the location of a property of an object in the form of an array (`[a, b, c]` corresponding to `object.a.b.c`), how can I execute the equivalent of the statement `delete object.a.b.c`?

EDIT: to clarify, I want to write a function that looks like this:

```
function deleteProperty(object, location) {
    // do stuff
}
```

and has the following effect:

```
var obj = {"foo": "FOO", "bar": "BAR", "a": {"b": "B"}};
deleteProperty(obj, [a, b]);
typeof obj.a.b === "undefined";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation and loop over until you get to the last one, then use the last one for the delete.

```js
function deleteProperty(obj, loc) {
  var last = loc.pop(); //grab last item from array
  var x = loc.reduce(function(o, x) {  //walk obj until all properties are there
    return o[x];
  }, obj);
  delete x[last];  //delete the last item from the array
}


var obj = {
  "foo": "FOO",
  "bar": "BAR",
  "a": {
    "b": "B"
  }
};
deleteProperty(obj, ["a", "b"]);
console.log(obj.a.b);
```

The code assumes that the path will be there, there are no checks for null/undefined/invalid path.

Answer (score 3):

In this statement

```
deleteProperty(obj, [a, b]);
```

`a` and `b` are variable names, which is incorrect syntax.

It is possible to implement this function if you pass string names:

```
deleteProperty(obj, ["a", "b"]);
```

It may look like this:

```js
function deleteProperty(obj, location) 
{
  var finalPropertyName = location.pop();

  location.forEach(function(key) { obj = obj[key]; });

  delete obj[finalPropertyName];
}

var obj = { foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR', a: { b: 'B' } };
deleteProperty(obj, ["a", "b"]);
console.log(obj);

var obj2 = { foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR', a: { b: 'B' } };
deleteProperty(obj2, ["a"]);
console.log(obj2);
```

Of course, this snippet is just an idea. You can implement it better, or add any functionality like checking for existing properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you're into using a library, try [lodash's `_.unset`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#unset). This example is straight from the docs:

> Removes the property at path of object.
>
> Note: This method mutates object.

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 7 } }] };
_.unset(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => true

console.log(object);
// => { 'a': [{ 'b': {} }] };

_.unset(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => true

console.log(object);
// => { 'a': [{ 'b': {} }] };
```

In your case, you'd do:

```
var obj = { foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR', a: { b: 'B' } };
_.unset(obj, ['a', 'b']);
typeof obj.a.b === 'undefined'; // => true
```

If you want want to mimic it with your own code, you can look at how they implement it [on line 4155 of the source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.15.0/lodash.js#L4155):

```
/**
 * The base implementation of `_.unset`.
 *
 * @private
 * @param {Object} object The object to modify.
 * @param {Array|string} path The path of the property to unset.
 * @returns {boolean} Returns `true` if the property is deleted, else `false`.
 */
function baseUnset(object, path) {
  path = isKey(path, object) ? [path] : castPath(path);
  object = parent(object, path);

  var key = toKey(last(path));
  return !(object != null && hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) || delete object[key];
}
```

You'll have to look up each of the functions used inside of there, though.